# Use a value in OneTimeSetup method(Nunit) in selenium webdriver in other tests

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am using selenium web driver in VS(c#). I need to write tests to validate data on a specific page.For that I have used Nunit's Onetime Setup method to setup reprocessing(navigating to that page) which works fine. Now I need the same web driver in my test method in order to perform validation on different elements(i will need that driver in all tests I have written) but what actually happens is that it does not perform operations in test method rather exists after perform Onetime Setup method.

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetUp ()
    {
    TagManagmentDataReader.GetDataForSelenium();

    driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    //For handling size of window
    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

    //sign in to private account
    IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Name("EmailAddress"));
    email.SendKeys(TagManagmentDataReader.email+Keys.Tab);

    }



[Test]
public void ValveListTest ()
    {
    //use the above driver here
    }
```

Comment: can you please add some more details? Are you getting any compile error? Can you share the code written in test method?

Comment: @noman Your explanation did not make clear idea, what is going on  OR What went wrong. Please share more details on flow.